# Disable link reference tooltip in browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I would like to know if there is a way to remove the "tooltip" (I don't know if is the right name for that element) that appears at the bottom-left of the screen when I stop the mouse cursor on a link.

[image]

I've taken this screenshot from my google search result page. As you can see the first site is underlined because the cursor is on it (you can't see the cursor because when I take a screenshot it disappears). The tooltip I'm talking about is the one at the bottom-left of the screen, surrounded by the smaller red rectangle.

I couldn't find any information about this element and, honestly, I don't know if it can be removed changing some browser setting.
I'm currently using Firefox and Chrome but I'm looking for a general solution.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+link+status+bar // It’s a bad idea (it robs the user of a useful tool of checking where a link goes before following it), and there is in general no good reason whatsoever for doing this.

Comment: @CBroe: I know it is a bad idea but I'm working on a really small (custom) device and the tooltip covers an important part of the page. I know, is a weird scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do it in older browsers, which would hide the status bar.

But to switch it off manually you could put this script in page somewhere...it removes href tag attaches onclick event listener...

```
$("body").on('mouseover', 'a', function (e) {
    var $link = $(this),
        href = $link.attr('href') || $link.data("href");

    $link.off('click.chrome');
    $link.on('click.chrome', function () {
        window.location.href = href;
    })
    .attr('data-href', href) //keeps track of the href value
    .css({ cursor: 'pointer' })
    .removeAttr('href'); // <- this is what stops Chrome to display status bar
});
```

Comment: Good jQuery solution, thank you for your effort. ;-)

Comment: no problem, it's always great to help with odd questions they keep my basic skills sharp

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the anchor tag with a button that when clicked executr a javascript function that links to your requested page

```
window.location.href = /route
```

Comment: Yea, this was a solution I was thinking about. Thank you for your answer ;-)

Comment: Can you elaborate this more , `window.location.href = /route` do you means using JS route system to handle links?

Comment: yes, routing with javascript

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers don't allow you to access the status bar to prevent phishing attacks. You can try this javascript but most likely it will be incompatibly with a majority of browsers:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function hidestatus(){
window.status='';
return true;
}

if (document.layers)
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEOVER | Event.MOUSEOUT | Event.MOUSEDOWN | Event.ONCLICK | Event.MOUSEMOVE | Event.MOUSEUP);

document.onmouseover=hidestatus;
document.onmouseout=hidestatus; 
document.onclick =hidestatus;
document.onmousemove=hidestatus;
document.onmouseup=hidestatus;
document.onmousedown =hidestatus
</script>
```